# How to e.target not everyone symbol in search?

Tags: reactjs

```
searchEmployee(e) {
    const {entityType} = this.state;
    const searchText = this.searchInput.value;

    if (e.target.value !== '' && searchText.length !== 0) {
        // window.clearInterval(this.timeout);
        this.drop.hide();

        if (searchText.length > 3) {
            this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    showSearchLoader: true,
                    result: [],
                    resultCounts: [],
                    hasMoreItems: false,
                    searchResultsEmpty: false,
                    entityType: 10,
                    searchAll: true
                });

                this.getResults(searchText, entityType, this.searchResultsCount, 0, false);
            }, 1000);
        }
    }

}
```

How to e.target.value doesnt send request (this.getResult get request) 
That would not send request each letter only when will finish to write(timeout)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `clearTimeout` with the number you store in `this.timeout` as argument every time you call `searchEmployee` to cancel the previous timeout.

```
searchEmployee(e) {
  const { entityType } = this.state;
  const searchText = this.searchInput.value;

  clearTimeout(this.timeout);

  if (e.target.value !== "" && searchText.length !== 0) {
    this.drop.hide();

    if (searchText.length > 3) {
      this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        this.setState({
          showSearchLoader: true,
          result: [],
          resultCounts: [],
          hasMoreItems: false,
          searchResultsEmpty: false,
          entityType: 10,
          searchAll: true
        });

        this.getResults(
          searchText,
          entityType,
          this.searchResultsCount,
          0,
          false
        );
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
}
```